# How to put constructors in another file in Julia?

Tags: module, constructor, julia, overriding, default-constructor

Julia structs and constructors are organized in separate files as follows:

```
# in file StructDef.jl

module StructDef
export MyStruct
struct MyStruct
    ia::Int
end
end


# infile Constructors.jl
module Constructors
using StructDef

function MyStruct( )
    # The following line throws the error: "ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching MyStruct(::Int64)"
    o = MyStruct(5) # should be replaced by
    #o = StructDef.MyStruct(5)
    return o
end
end



# in file main.jl
using StructDef
import Constructors

MyStruct(::Int64)"
m1 = Constructors.MyStruct( ) 

print(m1.ia,"\n");
```

On the lines commented, default constructor `MyStruct(::Int64)` is seemingly overridden by local function `MyStruct()` . If this is true, then is there a way to enable module `Constructors` to see the default constructor?

Comment: Your problem is that `StructDef.MyStruct` and `Constructors.MyStruct` are _not_ the same type, they are two separate types that happen to share the same name. Of you want to extend the constructor, try to define a method for `StructDef.MyStruct` instead.

Comment: I find the problem can be circumvented by simply renaming function  ```MyStruct```  to another name ( e.g. ```constructMyStruct``` ). The process under the hood might be that the compiler directs 'MyStruct()' to 'Constructors.MyStruct()' but 'Type.MyStruct(::Int)' is overridden in spite of having been imported with 'using ...' clause.

Answer (score 4):

you can have multiple files but only one module, this is the simplest way of doing it:

```
module MyModule
include("structs.jl")
include("functions.jl")
end
```

in your case, for code clarity I believe the "constructor" should be right after the definition

if you really want submodules and importing/exporting between them, have a look at the [documentation about submodules](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Submodules-and-relative-paths)